# unexpected (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) error

Tags: php

While Runnung the code its throwing error Can anybody helpme out

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\moduletwo\personal_view.php on line 64
```

code

```
                <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Sap Id :</th>
        <td><?php echo ". $row['sap_id'] .";?></td> //line 64

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
        <td><?php echo ". $row['first_name'] .";?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Try `<?php echo $row['sap_id']; ?>` this.

Comment: Why have you got `echo ''. $row['sap_id'] .'';`? You should just do `<?= $row['sap_id'] ?>`

Comment: Change this line: `<td><?php echo $row['sap_id'] ;?></td>`. Why do you need concatenation inside PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variables as strings.
Check the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Sap Id :</th>
        <td><?php echo $row['sap_id'];?></td> //line 64

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
    </tr>
```

Variables should not be within ".." , strings should.